# AEM/CQ application: PDF generator based on filtered results

Tags: javascript, java, pdf-generation, aem

I have an AEM component on a page that shows results based on filters within in the component. I want to add a functionality to the component to show a 'download pdf' button and once user clicks on it, the pdf should be generated based on the filtered results. Any inputs on how to approach this is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom servlet at server side that generate pdf format based on user's filter and return to client with content-type response header is application/pdf. When user click "download pdf" button, a request is called to your custom servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Back then, this article helped me giving the direction to implement a PDF generator using Apache FOP: http://www.citytechinc.com/us/en/blog/2013/02/using-apache-fop-to-generate-pdf-in-cq.html